# In Django modal how can i able to store both Integer and Float? It should return both accurate without converting

Tags: django, django-models

In Django i have model called MachineStatus and i have a field called machine heat. Here, my machine heat will be in integer ex: 6 celcius and also it will be in 6.5 celcius. How can i do this with integer and float dynamically?

class MachineStatus(models.Model):
heat = models.IntegerFiled(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Use `FloatField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField

Comment: Cool.. Thank you..